# multiselect box will not populate without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't post all my code but I try to get the important pieces in here. The problem I have is that I populate a multiselect box from the database then I get the already selected items and add those to the selected attribute. This all works in IE 7 which is what my testers are using, unfortunately I'm on IE 9 and most of my users are on IE 9. This code doesn't work on IE 9 or on firefox. The very weird thing is it will work if I stick an alert just after the call to the function that populates the multiselect.

after getting the selected values from the database through an ajax call I use

```
var oldValues.push($(this).find("Value_ID).text());
```

I do an alert of oldValues they are there 31,32,45 
then I use `$("drop2-input").val(oldValues);`

If I put an alert after this line it works.

I have spent the majority of the day checking every line of code there are no missing semicolons, no curly brackets out of place, and no parentheses out of place. Does anyone know of a way to make this work. 
Oh I already tried using a timeout to pause the code that just stoped the rest of the page from loading.

Comment: I know it's a lot of work, but make a jsFiddle and stick all your code in there. It is very likely that you've got a syntax error somewhere and you need extra eyes to find it.

Comment: Definitely post what you can...also, very weird that it works in IE7 of all things...I hate IE.

Comment: Does Firebug give any errors? If that's a copy/paste of code, you either have a `"` that doesn't belong in your `find()` or you're missing one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

Take a look at the JSFiddle I put togethre for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/douglasloyo/NEtJd/

```
    var json = [
        {name:"Texas", value:1},
        {name:"Texas Again", value:2},
        {name:"Texas Rocks!", value:3}];

    $.each(json, function(i, value) {
        $('#my-select').append($('<option>').text(value.name).attr('value', value.value));
    });

    <select id="my-select">
        <option>-Select-</option>
    </select>
```